# How to serialize external data structures?

Tags: c#, serialization

In my project, I use an external data strcuture `A` in my class `MyClass`. I would like to serialize my class with [DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as follows:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.my-url.com")]
public class MyClass {
  [DataMember]
  private A _a;
  ...
}
```

I am facing the problem, that the external data structure `A` does not support serialization with DataContracts. Therefore, my application crashes when trying to serialize class field `_a`.

Since the data structure `A` is external, there is no way for me to change it. Is it still possible to workaround this issue somehow?

Comment: Nice question. I'd like to add that this is a pretty common pattern. If you'd like read more about DTO http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you'll have to create some sort of wrapper class containing the serialization attributes. You should either copy the values, or expose the values via calls to the internal value of A's properties. You could use AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to copy values from one instance to the other.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the data structure A is external, there is no way for me to change it.

Exactly. Since you can't change the existing, external data structure, you should either map the data to your own, serializable [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), maybe using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), or create a wrapper for `A` which calls into the existing object's properties.

I'd argue you should do this anyway because it gives you, as opposed to the external library, control over what goes over the wire, and how it's structured/formatted.

Comment: Having the control over what goes over the wire is a good argument, I will kepp it in mind.